# My comparator class is not working

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

Ok, I have an object with multiple instance variables that I would like to sort by, so I read that i have to implement a comparator class and use it.

Basically its a plane class with PlaneSeats object as its member.
PlaneSeats has SeatID, CustomerID

I wish to print the occupied seats  by CustomerIDs, does anyone know how?

```
//This Prints it by SeatID (Since it starts from 0)
 for (int i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {
            if (seat[i].isOccupied()) {
                System.out.println("SeatID " + seat[i].getSeatID() + " assigned to CustomerID " + seat[i].getCustomerID());
            }
        }
```

my failed Comparator code is as follows: I hope to NOT use a seperate class though, hopefully so sort of array.sort function?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Comparator implements Comparator<Plane> {
    public int compare(Plane CustomerID[], Plane CustomerID[]) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.sort(CustomerID, new Comparator<Plane>() {
        public int compare(Plane p1, Plane p2) {
                           PlaneSeat ps1 = p1.getPlaneSeat();
                           PlaneSeat ps2 = p2.getPlaneSeat();
            return ps1.getSeatID().compareTo(ps2.getSeatID());
        }
    });
```

This will sort on basis of SeatId. If you want to sort on basis of CustomerId, replace getSeatID() with getCustomerID().

Comment: I kinda only have one plane, what i wish to do is only to compare the PlaneSeat's customerID and sort them accordingly.

Comment: okk..you just change it to - Arrays.sort(seat, new Comparator<PlaneSeat>() { public int compare(PlaneSeat ps1, PlaneSeat ps2) { return ps1.getCustomerID().compareTo(ps2.CustomerID());
} });

Comment: or there is one more way to solve it - define the natural ordering for PlaneSeat class by implementing your PlaneSeat class with Comparable<PlaneSeat> interface.

Answer (score 1):

This won't compile

```
public class Comparator implements Comparator<Plane> {
    public int compare(Plane CustomerID[], Plane CustomerID[]) {

    }
}
```

You are breaking the contract.

See this code for a possible solution.

PlaneSeat class definition

```
public class PlaneSeat {
   //Create your custom comparator strategy 
   public static final Comparator<PlaneSeat> CUSTOMER_COMPARATOR = new CustomerComparator();

    //fields
    private final Integer customerID;

        public PlaneSeat(Integer customerID){
            this.customerID= customerID;
        }

    private static class CustomerComparator implements Comparator<PlaneSeat>{

        @Override
        public int compare(PlaneSeat o1, PlaneSeat o2) {
             return o1.customerID.compareTo(o2.customerID); 
        }

    }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
      return "PlaneSeat [customerID=" + customerID + "]";
       }

}
```

Plane class

```
public class Plane{

    private List<PlaneSeat> seats;

    public List<PlaneSeat> getSeats() {
        return seats;
    }

    public void setSeats(List<PlaneSeat> seats) {
        this.seats = seats;
    }

        public void sortSeatsByCustomer(){
             Collections.sort(seats,PlaneSeat.CUSTOMER_COMPARATOR);
        }

        @Override
    public String toString() {
         return "Plane [seats=" + seats + "]";
    }

}
```

Then in your client code:

```
 public static void main(String args []){
    List<PlaneSeat> seats = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =10;i>0;i--)
      seats.add(new PlaneSeat(i--));

    Plane plane = new Plane();
    plane.setSeats(seats);
    System.out.println(plane);//print before sorting
    plane.sortByCustomers();
    System.out.println(plane);//after sorting by customer
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't name your class "Comparator", since that's already a Java interface name.

```
Plane CustomerID[]
```

This does not make sense.

Didn't I answer your prior question about seats?
Your PlaneSeat class should implement Comparable<PlaneSeat> and a method named

```
public int compareTo(PlaneSeat seat)
```

In this method, seat is the second seat, the object you're comparing with. The other object is

```
this
```

In this method, you can call the

```
getCustomerID()
```

method on the objects. It should look like:

```
public int compareTo(PlaneSeat seat) {
 if (this.getCustomerID() > seat.getCustomerID()) return 1;
 if (this.getCustomerID() < seat.getCustomerID()) return -1;
 return 0;
}
```

If this gives you the reverse order of what you wanted, swap 1 and -1.
Before your comment

```
//This Prints it by SeatID (Since it starts from 0)
```

call

```
seat = Arrays.sort(seat);
```

to sort the seats.

Comment: Wait uh, sorry im really new, but does that mean i dont need the comparator class?  I just put it in with the Plane class?

Comment: No, you don't need a comparator class, and no, you put it in the Seat class, since you are sorting seats, not planes.

Comment: he don't have a PlaneSeat array. so how comparable will work with PlaneSeat class. he has an array of Plane class with each Plane object having one PlaneSeat object. correct me if i m wrong

Comment: Look at the way OP accesses the seat elements. seat must clearly be an array. Plus, OP refers to "array.sort".

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement Comparator class again, it's defined as an interface and you have to implement it by naming a different class.